# trying to get random gifs at onClick from GIFs API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to display random gifs at onClick from GIFs API, but I am getting an error:

> 'Cannot read property 'images' of undefined'

when trying to get the URL for images.

Additionally, I have created a `handleClick` function to get random GIFs on every click.

Main.js

```
const Main = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

     useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?&limit=9&api_key=aIINKf0Pxb8MDhC2QPzTLbgvUXN6Uz7l')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseData => setData(responseData.data))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error)
          })
    },[])
    
    return(
        <div className="main hide">
            <GifList data={data} />    
        </div>
    )
}
export default Main
```

GifList.js

```
import Gif from './Gif'

const GifList = (props) => {

    let results = props.data
    let gif

        const pickRandomGif = () =>{
        let randomGifs = []

        for(let i=0; i<9; i++){
            let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)   
            randomGifs.push(randomNumber)
        }
        
        gif = randomGifs.map(random => 
            <Gif url={!results ? 'Loading...' : `${results[random].images.fixed_height.url}`} 
                 key={random.id} />
        )
    }

        const handleClick = (e) =>{
           e.preventDefault()
           pickRandomGif()
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="gif-list">
                    {gif}
                </ul>
                <button className="btn" onClick={handleClick}>Click here</button>
            </div>
         )
    }
export default GifList
```

Gif.js

```
const Gif = (props) => {
    return (
    <li className="gif-wrap">
        <img src={props.url} alt=""/>
    </li>
    )
  }
export default Gif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the data is loading,  `data` (and thus `results`) is an empty array. In your `GifList`, when data is empty `randomNumber` always equals 0. Then, when you map the `randomGifs` array, you try to access `results[0]`, which is `undefined` since results is empty. This causes the error, since `undefined` is not an object with property `images`.

You should add a check for whether `results` is empty (or whether `results[random]` is `undefined`) to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I tried initializing `results[random]` and it worked. Didn't get the need to check whether it's undefined or not. Would this be the right way since I am not getting any errors now?